# Existence of non-trivial homomorphism from projective module to ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, projective-module

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $P$ be a nonzero projective $R$-module.
I want to show that there exists a non-trivial homomorphism from $P$ to $R$.

I don't see how can I start. Can someone give a hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every $p\in P$, we have $R\to P$, $x\mapsto xp$. From this, you have a surjection $\bigoplus_{p \in P} R \to P$. Lift the identity $P\to P$ to non-trivial $P\to \bigoplus_{p \in P} R $. Project to the individual coordinates, they cannot all be trivial.

Comment: The product $R^P$ does not work, which is why I replaced it with the direct sum.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Ah, yes, thanks. Since we need projection to instead of inclusion from individual coordinates in the last step, I just boldly assumed without thought that we‘d use the product :)